# Lightning input type issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have created a lightning input with a dynamic input type . It's creating such a wried issue when I changed the value of 'v.type' number to text. The main problem is that when I click on the 'lightning:input', it's type, is number after that changed the value of an attribute using 'js Controller' into the text, is still showing the number type. I don't know why it's occurring. One more thing it's working fine when I changed the value number to date or another type

**COMPONENT**

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="type" type="String" default="number" />
   {!v.type}
   <lightning:input type="{!v.type}" label="" value=""/>

    <lightning:button label="Changed"  onclick="{! c.handleClick }"/>
    <lightning:button label="OtherChanged"  onclick="{! c.otherHandleClick }"/>
</aura:component>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 ({
   handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {                
      component.set("v.type",'text'); 
   },
   otherHandleClick : function(component, event, helper){
     component.set("v.type",'date'); 
   }
})
```

> Try this code and I am dam sure you will find the same issue which right now I am facing

Comment: Its working correctly when i am trying... can you give more info, like where are you using this component and how are you loading and any other info ?

Comment: First, you have to do click on the lightning input when type=number after that click on the 'Changed' button then if you select again 'lightning:input' or click on the input then still showing number input type